# “To burst fetters of violence” in non-historical context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

If I search “burst fetters” in Google there are only historical texts in results. So, can I say “Maybe, one bright day humanity will ***burst fetters*** of violence and cruelty” if I don’t mean anything related to the slavery but want to say “to get free, to get rid of”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

> "...humanity will burst **its** fetters"

.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Does other part of my sentence sound correctly?

Comment: Yes. Although I would either delete the comma after "maybe" or add a second comma after "bright day". I would favor deleting it.

Comment: hm, could you please explain why this comma should be deleted? (I’m not really good at English punctuation )

Comment: I agree with deleting the first comma and adding the second one after "day" and before "humanity. I also agree with "burst its fetters." It makes no sense  when it says "burst fetters of violence." I looked up the word "fetters" to see whether there was a definition I didn't know that Aer was trying to use. There is none, however.

Comment: Commas are notoriously tricky in English. There aren't a lot of consistent rules. However, after taking a fresh look at the sentence, I see the problem. My initial advice was wrong. The dependent clause is "Maybe one bright day". The comma should therefore be after "bright day", not after "maybe".

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically the answer "burst *its* fetters" or "burst *the* fetters" is fine, but at least to me, as a metaphor it does not quite flow.

Fetters are *bonds* or *chains*, like manacles or a ball and chain, something that prevents free movement.  It doesn't quite sound right to say these are made *of* violence and cruelty.  I feel it's slightly more logical to say instead:

> break free of their fetters **forged from** violence and cruelty

However, I'm not sure this is really an English argument, as I think the metaphor would not be quite right in *many* languages.  Systemic violence is *used* to create bonds, but it is not itself the binding material.

Answer (score 1):

We can also "*burst free* from" something.

> The prisoners burst free from the prison.
>
> One day, humanity will burst free from ...